# Does the C++ Standard Library define pi?

Tags: c++, std, pi

Does STL contain definition for pi (=3.14...)? Certainly, I can use old good `M_PI`, but it is non-standard and not cross-compiler compliant.

Comment: Nope. But you can use `acos(-1.0)` or something similar

Comment: Also see [Best platform independent pi constant?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21867617/1708801)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Boost.Math defines pi (and many other) mathematical constants to very high precision

```
#include <boost/math/constants.hpp>
long double pi = boost::math::constants::pi<long double>();
```

A full list is available [here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/math/doc/sf_and_dist/html/math_toolkit/constants/constants.html).

Comment: If you need double precision then you can use the "template-free" constant like this: `double pi = boost::math::double_constants::pi;`. If you need several constants, then you may use a namespace alias like `namespace bmath = boost::math::double_constants;` and then refer to `bmath::pi`, `bmath::root_pi`, etc.

Comment: In boost 1.57 the include is actually `<boost/math/constants/constants.hpp>`