# VS2017 'M_PI': undeclared identifier

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2017, llvm

I'm trying to compile a library in C++ as dll windows with visual studio 2017.

I have all C++/H compiled with clang 3.8 for android and it works.

I created a new project as dynamic library with LLVM as platform toolset. Now I'm trying to build but there is an error :

> Error    C2065   'M_PI': undeclared identifier

This error is present in many .cpp files. All linked .h contains :

```
#include <cmath>
```

I replaced by :

```
#define _USE_MATH_DEFINES // for C++  
#include <cmath>
```

But it change nothing. What can I do ?

Comment: [Possibly replicated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6563810/m-pi-works-with-math-h-but-not-with-cmath-in-visual-studio)

Comment: Also see [Best platform independent pi constant?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21867617/1708801)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is a known issue, try defining `_USE_MATH_DEFINES` as a definition in your project properties instead of the file itself.

This can be found in project properties -> C/C++ -> Preprocessor -> Preprocessor definitions.